# Java - Issue with Type Conversion in Expressions

Tags: java

I am just starting out with Java and practicing some sample programs. Below is the code i am trying out.

```
/*
   Using a cast
 */
class UseCast {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {

        int i;
        double d;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " / 3 with cast to double is " + (double) i
                    / 3);

            // > Why is the parenthesis around (i / 3) changing the result
            System.out.println(i + " / 3 with cast to double is "
                    + (double) (i / 3));
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

The first output works as expected.
In the second output, `(i / 3)` seems to be evaluated first as integer and then getting promoted to double for printing. What if i want to evaluate the expression as double and still retain the parenthesis around `i / 3`. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks Everyone for giving so many different ways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course do

```
((double) i / 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be doing something like below without even typecasting:

```
System.out.println(i + " / 3 with cast to double is "
                + (i / 3d));
```

For your case you are right, its `int/int` division and then you are type casting to double which doesn't makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to keep the cast outside the whole expression, you can multiply one of `i` or 3 by 1.0:

```
(double) (i * 1.0 / 3)
```

But now the cast is redundant since the expression is already evaluated to a `double`.

The result you're getting is because numbers are `int` by default in Java, 
`i / 3` will be calculated according to int-calculations, when having the result (0), the cast will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

`int/int` is considered as integer division, giving you integer result.
Either of the numerator or denominator has to be `double` to give you decimal answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is as follow:
(i / 3.0)

(int / int ) the division here will be considered as integer division

(int / dbl) or (dbl/int) or (dbl/dbl) the division here will be considered as floating point division.